# Java Timer counting too fast

Tags: java, timer

I want to write a timer class that counts every second till 0, but it seems to count too fast. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Eieruhr {

    private int x;

    public Eieruhr (int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Eieruhr eu = new Eieruhr(10);
        eu.start();
    }

    public void start(){
        for(int i = 0; i <= x; x--){
            long s = System.nanoTime();
            while( ((System.nanoTime() - s) / 100000000) < x);
            System.out.println("tick - " + x);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Thread.sleep(1000) in a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)`. Have a look at the code:

```
public class Eieruhr {
    private int x;

    public Eieruhr(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Eieruhr eu = new Eieruhr(10);
        eu.start();
    }

    public void start() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            System.out.println(new Date() + " tick - " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sat Oct 19 15:11:37 EEST 2019 tick - 0
Sat Oct 19 15:11:38 EEST 2019 tick - 1
Sat Oct 19 15:11:39 EEST 2019 tick - 2
Sat Oct 19 15:11:40 EEST 2019 tick - 3
Sat Oct 19 15:11:41 EEST 2019 tick - 4
Sat Oct 19 15:11:42 EEST 2019 tick - 5
```